# MapKit with UISearchBar

Tags: ios, api, mapkit, uisearchbar

So if I understand correctly you can no longer use certain Google APIs with iOS (ex. Google Places).  So how can we use the iOS MapKit with a UISearchBar to search for locations?  The map on my iPhone has a searchbar so if I, for example, type coffeshops I get all the pins in my area of local coffesshops.  If Apple is not using Google APIs what are they using to find this data? How can we developers tap into this search data?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapKit contains a search request to replace the outgoing Google APIs.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKLocalSearchRequest_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012892

Answer (score 0):

I have a small app with this feature.

Github: https://github.com/galahador/MapTag

UISearchBar - when you input data in bar, it shows on a map with a pointer (pin)

If you need any help, I can show code and explain everything.